# Recursively build a path from a python dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following python dictionary:

```
a = {'name': 'Kestral',
     'children': [
         {'name': 'Burtree Lane',
          'children': [
              {'name': 'ARCHIVE', 
               'children': []},
              {'name': 'Development',
               'children': [
                   {'name': 'Fee Proposals',
                    'children': []}]}]}]}
```

and i'm trying to write a recursive function to produce the following dictionary:

```
{'name': 'Kestral',
     'folder': 'Kestral',
     'children': [
         {'name': 'Burtree Lane',
          'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane',
          'children': [
              {'name': 'ARCHIVE',
               'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/ARCHIVE',
               'children': []},
              {'name': 'Development',
               'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/Development',
               'children': [
                   {'name': 'Fee Proposals',
                    'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/Development',
                    'children': []}]}]}]}
```

This is my python code:

```
def build_structured_dict(data, parent_path="/"):
  new_dict = {
      "name": data["name"],
      "folder": f"{parent_path}{data['name']}" if parent_path else data["name"],
      "children": [],
  }
  for child in data["children"]:
    child_path = f"{parent_path}{data['name']}" if parent_path else ""
    new_dict["children"].append(build_structured_dict(child, f"{child_path}/{child['name']}"))
  return new_dict
```

But this returns:

```
{'name': 'Kestral',
     'folder': '/Kestral',
     'children': [{
         'name': 'Burtree Lane',
         'folder': '/Kestral/Burtree LaneBurtree Lane',
         'children': [{
             'name': 'ARCHIVE',
             'folder': '/Kestral/Burtree LaneBurtree Lane/ARCHIVEARCHIVE',
             'children': []},
            {'name': 'Development',
             'folder': '/Kestral/Burtree LaneBurtree Lane/DevelopmentDevelopment',
             'children': [{
                 'name': 'Fee Proposals',
                 'folder': '/Kestral/Burtree LaneBurtree Lane/DevelopmentDevelopment/Fee ProposalsFee Proposals',
                 'children': []}]}]}]}
```

Can someone help me in removing these duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating the "name" attribute both as argument to the recursive call (`child["name"]`) as in that recursive execution itself `data["name"]`, causing the duplication.

Here is a correction to your code, which keeps the initial slash which you also produced in your code:

```
def build_structured_dict(data, parent_path="/"):
  path = f"{parent_path}{data['name']}"
  new_dict = {
      "name": data["name"],
      "folder": path,
      "children": [],
  }
  for child in data["children"]:
    new_dict["children"].append(build_structured_dict(child, path + "/"))
  return new_dict
```

If you don't want the initial slash (as depicted in your desired output), then set the default value for the second parameter to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the child name twice and the default value of `parent_path` is the cause of the leading slash. It's also not necessary to start with an empty list and add children one by one, you can use a list comprehension:

```
def build_structured_dict(data, parent_path=""):
  new_path = f"{parent_path}{data['name']}"
  return {
      "name": data["name"],
      "folder": new_path,
      "children": [build_structured_dict(child, new_path+'/') for child in data["children"]],
  }

{'name': 'Kestral', 'folder': 'Kestral', 'children': [{'name': 'Burtree Lane', 'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane', 'children': [{'name': 'ARCHIVE', 'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/ARCHIVE', 'children': []}, {'name': 'Development', 'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/Development', 'children': [{'name': 'Fee Proposals', 'folder': 'Kestral/Burtree Lane/Development/Fee Proposals', 'children': []}]}]}]}
```